# I am trying to import a CSV file into PostgreSQL, but I am getting error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table using the \copy command in the psql command-line tool. The table contains a date_hour column in the format "01.01.2017-17:00" (day.month.year-hour:minute), and I want to treat it as a timestamp without time zone during the import.

However, when I execute the following command in my terminal:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d wattmon -U wattmon -c "\copy solar_data FROM 'C:\Users\****\Downloads\Solar Power Plant Data.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"
```

I get

```
ERROR: time zone displacement out of range: "01.01.2017-17:00"
CONTEXT: COPY solar_data, line 19, column date_hour: "01.01.2017-17:00"
```

How can I resolve this issue and successfully import the data from the CSV file? Is there a way to convert the date_hour values to the correct timestamp format during the import process?

Note: I have already tried creating the solar_data table with the `date_hour` column using the `TIMESTAMP` data type, but the error persists. Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

update:Introduction:
In this troubleshooting journey, i encountered challenges while attempting to insert data from a CSV file into a PostgreSQL database. The issues primarily revolved around data formatting, permissions, and time zone displacements. This Stack Overflow answer aims to discuss the problems faced, their solutions, and the steps taken to resolve them.

Problem 1: Permission Denied
The initial hurdle was encountered when trying to import the CSV file using the 'COPY' command in PostgreSQL. The error message "could not open file for reading: Permission denied" pointed to a file access restriction.

Solution 1:
To resolve this, we checked the permissions of the CSV file and ensured that the PostgreSQL service account (usually "postgres" or specified during installation) had read access to the file.

Problem 2: Time Zone Displacement Out of Range
After resolving the permission issue, we successfully imported the data into a temporary table. However, a new challenge emerged when trying to convert the "Date-Hour(NMT)" to "timestamp without time zone" format. The error "time zone displacement out of range" occurred.

solution:the postgresql has limitation that it only accepts 14 hour format or something and that would require a lot of work i'd like some help in this stage now

Answer (score 0):

1. You will first need to create a temporary table (staging table) to hold the date_hour values before converting them to timestamps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_solar_data (date_hour_text text, other_column1 data_type1, other_column2 data_type2, ...);
```

Replace other_column1 data_type1, other_column2 data_type2, ... with the actual columns and data types that match your CSV file.

2. Use the '*\copy*' command to import data from the csv file into the temporary table created above.

```
\copy temp_solar_data (date_hour_text, other_column1, other_column2, ...) 
FROM 'C:\Users****\Downloads\Solar Power Plant Data.csv' 
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

Modify the path and columns values to fit your requirements.

3. Use an '**UPDATE**' statement with the '**TO_TIMESTAMP**' fucntion to convert the date_hour text values to timestamps.

```
UPDATE temp_solar_data
SET date_hour = TO_TIMESTAMP(date_hour_text, 'DD.MM.YYYY-HH24:MI');
```

4. Insert the converted data from the temporary table into your main '**solar_data**' table:

```
INSERT INTO solar_data (date_hour, other_column1, other_column2, ...)
SELECT date_hour_text, other_column1, other_column2, ...
FROM temp_solar_data;
```

Remember to modify the column values here to match your actuals columns again.

Comment: thank you for answering me so quickly ,anyways  i  used the code based on your answer `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_solar_data (
    date_hour TIMESTAMP,
    wind_speed NUMERIC,
    sunshine NUMERIC,
    air_pressure NUMERIC,
    radiation NUMERIC,
    air_temperature NUMERIC, relative_air_humidity NUMERIC, system_production NUMERIC);..........ERROR:  could not open file "C:/Users/Salil/Downloads/Solar Power Plant Data.csv" for reading: Permission denied HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`

Comment: as you can see i am having  trouble granting privledges to wattmon and im actually fairly new to postgresql i have granted myself permissions wherever i could using pgadmin 4